# Remove head from array of strings

Tags: c

I have

```
char ** command; //command = ls -l -a
```

I need a

```
char * arguments[sizeof(command)-1]; //arguments = -l -a
```

With everything I tried I get `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

My latest try has been:

```
char ** get_arguments (char ** command){

    for (int i=0; i<sizeof(command); i++){
        command[i]=command[i+1];
    }
    return command;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv){

   char ** arguments= get_arguments (argv);

    for(int i = 0; i<sizeof(arguments); i++){

        printf("%s ",arguments[i]);
    }

}
```

Comment: `sizeof command` evaluates to the size of a pointer. That is nothing you should use as limit for array indexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays in C work quite differently from many other languages. The arrays themselves don't contain any metadata such as length, the only thing that's available is the raw bytes themselves and the type of the pointer (in this case, `char **`/an array of `char *`).

What this means is that your `get_arguments` function has no clue how long the `command` array is; the `sizeof(command)` isn't returning the *length* of the command array, it's returning the size of `command`, which is just a *pointer* to the array. So what's happening is that you're reading off the end of the array!

If you were to re-run using something like `ls -a -l -h a b c d e f g h i j k l m n` as the input to your method, you won't segfault anymore (because the array is longer now, you're no longer reading off the end), but you'll have a different problem. Rather than `sizeof(command)` being too big, it's too small!

What you need to do instead is analogous to what's in `main`, where you pass an `int` that's the size of the array (analogous to `argc`), and then the array itself (analogous to `argv`). Then, instead of looping from 0->`sizeof(command)`, you'll loop from 0->`len`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass information about the array size. `sizeof` of pointer gives the size of pointer only, not the size of the referenced object. When used on an **array** `sizeof` returns size in bytes, **not elements**.

```
int get_arguments (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argv && argc > 0)
    {   
        if(argc > 1)
            memmove(&argv[0], &argv[1], (argc - 1) * sizeof(argv[0]));
        argc--;
    }
    return argc;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{

    printf("Before\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++){

        printf("argv[%d] = %s \n", i,  argv[i]);
    }
    argc = get_arguments (argc, argv);
    printf("-------------------------------------\nAfter\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++){

        printf("argv[%d] = %s \n", i,  argv[i]);
    }

}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/TWx7osjc1

Answer (score 0):

The fun thing about using pointers to pass around arrays, is that they don't have to point to the first element of an array. It is perfectly fine to work with sub arrays by pointing to any element. You just let your pointer point to the first element of your sub array

```
/* 
   Have a shared sub-array of whatever `argv` points at, skipping the first
   element, and letting `arguments` point at it
 */ 
char **arguments = argv + 1;

/* or alternative: */
char **arguments = &argv[1];

/* You could also just "advance `argv` to the next element" */
argv++;
```